# Retrieve Data from MySQL table codeigniter syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, syntax-error

So I get error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in /application/controllers/c_view_users.php on line 19".

I can't figure out why.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_view_users extends CI_controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index() {

    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('m_users');
    //$this->load->library('table');
    $data['result'] = $this->m_users->get_contents();
    $this->load->view('view_users', $data);
}
?>
```

And model:

```
<?php
class m_claims extends CI_model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    //Get CI Instance
    //$CI = & get_instance();
    //$CI->load->model( EASYPHP_CORE_DIR . 'user_auth' , 'user_auth');

    //--------------- Table name, caption and controller ---------------
    $this->tableName = "users";
    $this->caption = "Users";
    $this->controllerName = "c_view_users";
    $this->recordsPerPage = 25;


    //--------------- Pages and function setup ---------------
    $this->add = true;
    $this->update = true;
    $this->view = true;
    $this->printView = true;
    $this->delete = true;
    $this->allowQuickSearch = true;


function get_contents() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('scouts');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result();
}
}

}
}?>
```

and view

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Content</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach($result  as $r): ?>
<tr><?php echo $r->content; ?>

  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php
```

Can anyone help spot my error on the controller? I've tried process of elimination with no luck. From here, I thought my syntax looked right.

Comment: is that your whole controller? you're missing a closing brace `}` at the end

Comment: apparently my sharp eye isn't so sharp. Thanks.

Comment: @tkdlax you have posted `C_view_users` controller loaded  `users` model and you posted code of `m_claims` model. Any relation ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to this:

```
<?php
    class m_claims extends CI_model {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            //Get CI Instance
            //$CI = & get_instance();
            //$CI->load->model( EASYPHP_CORE_DIR . 'user_auth' , 'user_auth');

            //--------------- Table name, caption and controller ---------------
            $this->tableName = "users";
            $this->caption = "Users";
            $this->controllerName = "c_view_users";
            $this->recordsPerPage = 25;


            //--------------- Pages and function setup ---------------
            $this->add = true;
            $this->update = true;
            $this->view = true;
            $this->printView = true;
            $this->delete = true;
            $this->allowQuickSearch = true;
        }

        function get_contents() {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('scouts');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $result = $query->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I get the reformatting, but really syntactically, isn't it the same? I tried it and still get the same error referencing the controller syntax